# Symfony2 - Logging out of one firewall

Tags: security, authentication, symfony, firewall

I have two firewalls, "admin" and "client", in my Symfony2 project. They both use the same entity provider.

The problem I'm having is that when I log out of one firewall, I'm logged out of the other as well. I'd prefer this not to be the case.

Is there something wrong with my implementation or strategy. I did play around with the idea of having one firewall and managing access to the admin and client areas via user roles. However, this doesn't avoid the logout scenario I described above.

Below is my security.yml (a bit simplified).

```
    admin:
        pattern: ^/admin
        form_login:
            provider:      acme_userbundle
            login_path:    admin_login
            check_path:    admin_security_check
        logout:
            path:   admin_logout
            target: admin_login
        anonymous: false

    client:
        pattern: ^/client
        form_login:
            provider:      acme_userbundle
            login_path:    client_login
            check_path:    client_security_check
        logout:
            path:   client_logout
            target: client_login
        anonymous: false
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Solution

The solution is to add the following configuration line:

```
invalidate_session: false
```

(Reference: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/security.html)

That line should be added to the `logout` configuration block of every firewall. This way, when you logout from one of them, the session won't be destroyed, and you will be kept logged in on the other ones.

### Example

```
security:
    ...
    firewalls:
        ...
        admin:
            pattern: ^/admin
            ...
            logout:
                path:   admin_logout
                ...
                invalidate_session: false #This line should do the trick!
            ...

         client:
             pattern: ^/client
             ...
             logout:
                 path:   client_logout
                 ...
                 invalidate_session: false #This line should do the trick!
             ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Following solution worked in Sf 2.0.x, but i'm not sure it still is useful...

When you log in, you are identified with your session and a security entry is created for each firewalls, named as 'security_'. So, in your case, to log out from client area, you can achieve it with :

```
// $session is Session service from container
$session->remove('security_client');
```

Comment: Check my answer for the documented way to do it.